# Reading a file representing word frequencies in Wikipedia, for clustering analysis

Tags: python, python-2.x, time-limit-exceeded, file, wikipedia

I am writing a system that will run Kmeans to determine the most used words in Wikipedia. I do this by building a core set with streaming data. Wikipedia is 50TB but after a year of processing I was given data of size 14 GB which I need to parse and I want it to run fast. From client I send server 10000 points which are processed.

**CODE:**

```
import gc
import time

class point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w

def parse(pathToFile):
    myList = []
    with open(pathToFile) as f:
        for line in f:
            s = line.split()
            x, y, w = [int(v) for v in s]
            obj = point(x, y, w)
            gc.disable()
            myList.append(obj)
            gc.enable()
    return myList

if __name__ == "__main__":
    startTime = time.time()
    L = parse('C:/Users/user/workspace/finalSub/api/data100mb.txt')
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - startTime))
```

Parsing a `114MB` file takes **130 seconds** when I've been told it should take few seconds.

I tried splitting the data to multiple chunks and apply multiprocessing, but it ended up that reading from multiple files is bad and results in even longer time time to parse. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620323/why-is-reading-multiple-files-at-the-same-time-slower-than-reading-sequentially).

**File Sample:**

```
1 1 1
1 2 1
1 3 1
1 4 1
.
.
1 N 1
2 1 1
2 2 1
2 3 1
2 4 1
.
.
2 N 1
```

How should I parse the file correctly or access it in-order to make it faster?

Comment: In Python a class's name should be capitalized. So your class's name  should be `Point`. Variables and functions' names should be written in lower case with an underscore if the name consists of more than one word. So your variables' names should be: `my_list`, `l` and `start_time`, respectively.

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib does that affect runtime ?

Comment: I don't think so. It's about style. This is a comment, not intended to be an answer. See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions

Comment: What do you intend to do with the results? What is supposed to happen when the middle coordinate is `N`?

Comment: @200_success ,I take 10000 points and send to server to process them depends on algorithm.

Comment: Could you tell us what kind of processing you had in mind?

Comment: @200_success yes sir, I am writing a system that will run Kmeans to determind the most used words in Wikipedia. I do this by building a coreset with streaming data. Wikipedia is 50TB but after a year of processing I was given data of size 14 GB which I need to parse and i want it to run fast. From client I send server 10000 points which are processed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel), especially with common tasks that are likely to have optimized implementations. In this case, I recommend trying [`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to read the file. Then, the matrix can be fed to [`sklearn.cluster.KMeans()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

Comment: It is a problem. I must have the points in a list, or the `14GB` will grow to `50TB`.  A Wikipedia article contains 5000 words for example,  w is the weight which is always 1. each point corresponds to a `(x, y)` where x is the wikipedia article and y corresponds to the word. The word `else` might be `20000`  If I turn this into a matrix I will have a huge space waste. Or am I missing something, sir.
Each word is assigned a number id. i.e `Else` --> `20000`

Comment: Why would the resulting matrix from `read_csv()` be any larger than your list of `point`s? Either way, it's the same two-dimensional table containing the same data.

Comment: The bottleneck ended up being the data being sent to server. Sending objects was costly! moved to binary and it went 40 times faster. :)

Answer (score 4):

I would try the following things:

- remove the `gc` manipulation code
- use [`__slots__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots) for the `Point` class - should result into memory handling and performance improvements

  ```
  class Point:
      __slots__ = ['x', 'y', 'w']

      def __init__(self, x, y, w):
          self.x = x
          self.y = y
          self.w = w
  ```
- use a *list comprehension* instead of appending (generally faster):

  ```
  def parse(path):
      with open(path) as f:
          return [Point(*(int(s) for s in line.split())) 
                  for line in f]
  ```
- try the [`PyPy` Python implementation](http://pypy.org/) (with the latest `PyPy` on my machine the 100k line file is parsed about 4 times faster than the Python 3.6)

Comment: Up from `130seconds` to `170 seconds`.  **:-(**

Comment: @TonyTannous what about the `PyPy`?

Comment: I need to try it. Though I rather a software gain and not some other technique from outside code.